# Could we fix the dates in the example question in SO tour?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, tour

The new top nav-bar helped me navigate to the fancy [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) again, but the example question caught my eye.  The example shows that the question was *answered* a year before it was *asked*.

[image]

Minor issue, I know.  But could we fix this, *please*?

Comment: This **can** happen when questions are merged (an older into a newer, which is rare, but happens)

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware that this can really happen.  Thanks.